# Badges earned on Meta are not shown in the badge tracker

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress, convention-badge

I have seen that some badges earned on Stack Overflow require you to have a certain achievement on the Meta site.

For example, I received the [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) badge for having a post with a score of 2 or more on Meta, which was never shown on the Stack Overflow badge tracker. There is also the moderator-required badge [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), which is for having 10 posts with a score of 2 or more on Meta.

Should these badges be shown on the Stack Overflow badge tracker?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>First, those badges aren't technically *required* for being a moderator... the badges that make up your moderator score are just indicators of how broad of a contributor you are to the site and its various functions; candidates with higher scores (more of the score-badges) have contributed in more ways, e.g. they are active on Meta or are prolific editors/reviewers.</strike>

As for the tracking part, they probably don't appear because Meta rep, scores, and badges are processed in a weird way... reputation, for example, is tied to your site reputation and is not even updated as often as the main site rep is. Badges, however, are totally separate between Main and Meta; progress for Meta badges is typically tracked on Meta. Interestingly, Quorum and Convention aren't tracked on Meta, either.

I can't speak to whether there was a technical reason preventing these badges from being shown, but it's likely that the above reason was enough of a complication for them to say 'we just won't show these'. Maybe the badges were added specially for moderator elections and weren't added to the badge tracker for that reason?

If I ran the zoo, I'd say they should be shown/tracked.

Comment: I see. I thought they were moderator-required because it said `an eligible candidate must have the following badges`

Comment: @JerryD Ah, actually yeah, I forgot about that caveat. I'll update my answer; you're right.

Comment: [Nominations for zookeeper are currently in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/election)

Comment: @CodyGray I think mods are a bit below zookeeper in this analogy :-) Unless you're saying mods have control over what badges can and can't be tracked in user profiles?

Comment: Nah, [zookeeper sounds about right](https://www.mysanantonio.com/news/local/article/A-slice-of-life-at-the-zoo-Cleaning-poop-4702799.php). No control over badge tracking, though.

Answer (score 2):

There was a previous request on Meta Stack Exchange to make the Convention badge trackable, but it was [declined for technical reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273010/let-the-convention-badge-be-tracked-as-next-badge):

> Meta is in a separate database, which makes it a lot harder to run checks for things because it requires connecting to a second database. Running checks like this in real time simply isn't a good use of resources or worth the performance issues it would cause, which is why the Meta and Chat badges were not included in the badge trackers.